# Upload file to subdirectory with specific name when subdirectories don't exist?

Tags: c#, file-permissions, winscp, winscp-net

Maybe this is a four-part question:

1. Upload to subdirectory/ies
2. Subdirectories don't exist
3. Use different remote filename than local file
4. Subdirectories should have explicit permissions (similar to root problem in [WinSCP .NET assembly - How to set folder permissions after creating directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726700/winscp-net-assembly-how-to-set-folder-permissions-after-creating-directory))

Attempted:

```
var localPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
var remoteFolder = "/some/directory/beneath/root";
var slash = "/"; // maybe given as '/' or '\'...
var remotePath = remoteFolder + slash + "destination.ext1.ext2.txt";
var session = new Session(sessionOptions);
var result = session.PutFiles(localPath, remotePath, false, new FileTransferOptions { FilePermissions = new FilePermissions { Octal = "700" }, KeepTimestamp..., etc });
result.Check();
```

throws exception `Cannot create remote file '/some/directory/beneath/root/destination.ext1.ext2.txt'. ---> WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: No such file or directory.`

I was finally able to make the subdirectories with the correct permissions via [the crazy workaround indicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24730695/1037948) by creating the subdirectory structure in my temp path and using `PutFiles` on the *first folder*:

```
var tempRoot = Path.GetTempPath();
var tempPath = Path.Combine(tempRoot, remoteFolder);
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);

// only need to upload the first segment, PutFiles will magically grab the subfolders too...
var segment = remoteFolder.Substring(0, remoteFolder.IndexOf(slash, StringComparison.Ordinal));
if( !this.DoesFolderExist(segment) )
{
        // here's the workaround...
        try
        {
            this._session.PutFiles(Path.Combine(tempRoot, segment), segment, false, new TransferOptions { FilePermissions = this._transferOptions.FilePermissions }).Check();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // workaround for bug in .NET assembly prior to 5.5.5/5.6.1 beta
            // although I never hit this catch, maybe I've got a new enough version?
        }
}
Directory.Delete(tempPath); // finish workaround
```

but this was way too unintuitive.

Comment: The question is not clear. Does the target directory `/some/directory/beneath/root/` exist or not? Can you elaborate on your four points?

Comment: Per point #2 -- the subdirectories don't exist.  What's not clear?  I want to upload a file to a subdirectory that doesn't exist, but use a different filename, and ensure that the file and directories it exists under have the same permissions.

Comment: What subdirectories? The `/some/directory/beneath/root/` must exist. I do not understand the *ensure that the file and directories it exists under have the same permissions*.

Answer (score 1):

ad 1) WinSCP does not (generally) create the target directory of the upload. It must exist prior to the upload. You can test the existence using the [`Session.FileExists`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_fileexists) and create the directory using the [`Session.CreateDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_createdirectory), if not. WinSCP, of course, creates the directories you are uploading, if needed.

ad 3) You specify different target name in the `remotePath` argument of the [`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles):

```
session.PutFiles(@"C:\path\original.txt", "/home/user/newname.txt");
```

ad 4) You specify permissions of uploaded file/directory using the [`TransferOptions.FilePermissions`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#filepermissions). Note that WinSCP implicitly adds `x` permission to directories for every group, where `r` permission is granted. So when you specify `600` permissions for batch upload, the `600` is used for files, while `700` is used for directories. If you need to use different permissions for different files/directories, you need to upload them one by one.

Comment: I think what confuses me is the seeming contradiction between "WinSCP does not (generally) create the target directory" and "WinSCP, of course, creates the directories you are uploading".  I had to reread that a couple times before it clicked -- the destination directories must exist, and so you can either create them one-by-one (`CreateDirectory`), or take advantage of the second statement to make the subdirectories locally (just empty folders) and then upload _them_ to create them all at the same time (`PutFiles(localRoot, remoteRoot)`).

Comment: The point is that if you are uploading say `C:\folder\*` to `/home/user/folder/`, the target directory `/home/user/folder/` must exist. But if there are subdirectories (empty or not) in the `C:\folder` (matching the mask, if different from `*`), such as `C:\folder\a`, they are automatically created in the target folder, i.e. as `/home/user/folder/a` (unless they exist already, of course).